# html/js onclick not working as required

Tags: javascript, html

Html/js is not working as expected. When I click on "Send Email" button, I was expecting message of "An Email has been sent to your address" should display permanently . But what actually happening is message displaying hardly 1 sec and disappearing. Same happening when I click again and again but not displaying permanently.

```
<form>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <label>Email Address:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email" />
    </td>
  </tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td><br/><br/>
    <input id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Send Email" onclick="val()" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<div id="msg">
</div>


<script>
function val (){
  if (document.getElementsByName("Email").value =="")
   {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML='<p>No data entered</p>'
   }
  else
   {
   document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML='<p>An Email has been sent to your address</p>'
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: By submitting the form, you're causing the browser to either navigate to a new page or reload the page. Have you considered submitting through Ajax instead of through a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is a `form`, and the Send Email button is a `submit button` when you click on it it submits the form, which triggers a page refresh. That is the reason why message appears only for a short while.

You can prevent the form from submitting via javascript.

if you do not need a form (you are not doing anything with it right now) you can also simply remove the form.

Comment: Exactly what I need. I changed type="submit" to "button" and It's working as expected. Cheers :)